# Zend Gdata SSL always required?

Tags: zend-framework, ssl, zend-gdata

I've been trying out the Zend Framework 1.12 Gdata library. I've tried some random code snippets from the interweb, but my application keeps returning the needed SSL installation onto my server (localhost). I'm wondering if the SSL certificate is always needed for using the Gdata library? It would pretty much such if so. Could someone inform me some more on this subject... couldn't find a real answer to it on the web.

Comment: Could anyone answer my question, because I really need some Google data but I'm not always in the possession of a SSL certificate.

Comment: add more details about what you are trying to do (how does your script look like) and post specific error details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i guess you have to remove the comment on the following line by going into php.ini file..

extension=php_openssl.dll

it may solve your problem.